# From whose perspective the author is saying in the following fragment

Tags: meaning, british-english, translation, literature

I am trying to translate the short story by J. M. Coetzee but can't understand how exactly to interpret the sentence in the second paragraph. The story narrates about a young boy who finds a strange circle in the field. Next we have the following:

> He thought of it as a fairy circle, a circle where fairies came at night to dance by the light of the tiny sparkling rods that they carried in the picturebooks he read, or perhaps by the light of glowworms. But in the picturebooks the fairy circle was always in a clearing in a forest, or else in a glen, whatever that might be. There were no forests in the Karoo, no glens, no glowworms; were there even fairies?

I am particularly interested in the second sentence. Does *whatever that might be* mean that the boy doesn't know what the word *glen* means? If so, where did he take this word? From picturebooks? The word looks for me quiet encyclopedic and as if it is a label for an image of fairy circle of mushrooms. So it is unlikely that fairies dancing may be mentioned in an encyclopedia. Does then the boy mix two kinds of books - picturebooks about fairies and an encyclopedia? Or *glen* is still a normal word to appear in a picturebook? Do you think a fairy circle of mushrooms is supposed to exist as a double meaning at all?

Depending on the answers I am going to choose:

1. how to translate *glen* - more encyclopedic or not;
2. should I rely on existing tradition of naming circles of mushrooms in a target language or not.

Comment: It's not a very well thought-out usage. The writer is getting confused between the fact that ***he*** isn't sure of the exact definition of the word "glen" (and/or suspects that at least some of his readers might also lack that knowledge), and the vocabulary of his ***subject***. Obviously the boy being written about doesn't need to know or care what a "glen" is, since we're explicitly told ***he gets his understanding from picture books***.  If a picture happens to have the word "glen" underneath the image, it makes no sense for the boy to wonder what it means - ***he's looking at one**!*

Comment: I think everything in the text cited is a way of thought of the boy, his internal dialogue, and the commentary about glen is boy’s voice, not author’s.

Comment: [Picture books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_book) normally combine text and pictures, so they might well use the word "glen" in text. Of course FumbleFingers may know better than a winner of the Nobel Prize for Literature, but I doubt it.

Comment: @Ihor Shnaider: Yes - the entire text is basically telling us what the boy thought. But it makes no sense for the boy to be wondering what a "glen" is if he only encountered the word in ***picturebooks***. Obviously Coetzee himself (or any typical South African boy, such as he would remember *himself* as being, in his youth) might well not know that essentially Scottish word. But that would only make sense for boys who came across it in *pictureless* texts, which isn't the case for our subject here! Coetzee is lazily / thoughtlessly trotting out an inappropriate stereotypical cliche.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it means that he doesn't know what a 'glen' is. It's a mainly Scottish word for a valley - not a particularly obscure word, at least to British people. I googled *fairy glen* and found references to several places of that name in Scotland and Northern England; picturesque valleys where people imagine that the fairies might gather. The expression might well have been used in one of the boy's picture books.

*Glen* doesn't mean a [fairy ring](https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/blog/2019/08/what-is-a-fairy-ring/), though you might picture fairy rings in a fairy glen!

Comment: Thank you Kate. Sorry for not being clear - I didn't mean that *glen* is a fairy ring, I just imagined some label in an encyclopedia like _fairy circle in a glen_. Anyway, you answered my question by saying that *glen* is still a relevant word for children books. So the author doesn't imply any encyclopedias or mushroom circles in the boy's mind.

Comment: Certainly he wouldn't have had to look in an encyclopaedia for the word _glen_! But he thinks of fairies when he sees the circle on the ground because of the images of fairies dancing in a circle round a 'fairy ring', which is in fact the natural way that some mushrooms grow.

Comment: It is exactly because the word glen is common that the boy assigned it here correctly, without knowing its exact meaning. As a low meadow, it contrasts well with *forest*. Five-year-olds can use phrasing correctly without knowing why, like "I'm outraged. Mortified. Wadthafahk."